# Why can't a group with more than p-1 elements be cyclic?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Let p be any element in a prime.
Suppose a group G has more than p-1 elements of order p.

Why can't the group be cyclic?

Any hint is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Crostul I have edited the question. There was a slip

Comment: Can this be solved using only cyclic group theorems?

Comment: Suggestion: Think contrapositively. Suppose $(G, \cdot)$ is a cyclic group; how many elements of order $p$ can $G$ contain? (Separately, the current title seriously mismatches the question.)

Comment: The title doesn't agree with the question....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this can be solved using basic cyclic groups' lemmas, and the most important for us now is:

**Lemma:** If $\;G\;$ is a finite cyclic group, then there is *one unique* subgroup of order any divisor of $\;|G|;$ .

Thus, clearly $\;p\,\mid|G|\;$ by the given data. If $\;G\;$ was cyclic it'd have one **unique** subgroup of order $\;p\;$ . Finish now the argument...

Comment: I can see where you argument is going but I have some doubts along the way.
There are p-1 elements of order p. This means that if the element $a$ in that set of p-1 has order p. This means $a^{p}$=e.
You invoked the Fundamental theorem of cyclic group but I fail to see how p divides the order of G, say n.
However, if I were to refer to Lagrange theorem, it becomes clear that the order of an element divides the order of a group.
This is where my doubt persists.

Comment: @Mathematicing You wrote that $\;G\;$ has more than $\;p-1\;$ elements **of order** $\;p\;$ , which means $\;p\;$ divides $\;|G|\;$ , by Lagrange.

Comment: I can understand it by invoking Lagrange. But this would 'mask' my lack of understanding on a more robust level.

Comment: @Mathematicing I really have no idea what you mean...Lagrange's theorem is way more basic *usually* than results on cyclic groups and stuff.

Comment: Can you get around without using Lagrange? Cyclic group is a weak area to me. It doesn't help me to use 'short cuts'

Comment: @Mathematicing I'm not sure, but I can't also understand why would we. It's like you asking me whether we can go around something in college level withour using the multiplication table of seven: perhaps, but why would we? To do this exercise, I think it must be pretty old and elementary that if an element of a finite group has order $\;p\;$ then $\;p\;$ divides the order of the group...

Comment: How would you then attempt to solve this if asked not to invoke Lagrange theorem....?

Comment: @Mathematicing Honestly, I wouldn't. In fact, I didn't: it was **you** that brought Lagrange, not me. Of course, I use a pretty basic result that, in my or your case, can be proved with Lagrange, but that's something I wouldn't care when attacking this question, just as I wouldn't even care to remark that $\;7\cdot8=56\;$ because this or that when trying to evaluate some function's derivative. Muliplication tables is old stuff *then*, already.

Answer (score 0):

Sketch: Suppose (for contradiction) that $G$ is cyclic.  Let $x$ be order $p$, then $\langle x\rangle$ is a subgroup of order $p$ with exactly $p-1$ elements of order $p$.  Since there are more than $p-1$ elements of order $p$, let $y\not\in\langle x\rangle$ be order $p$.  Then $\langle y\rangle$ is also a subgroup of order $p$ (and is not equal to $\langle x\rangle$).  This contradicts the uniqueness of subgroups of order $p$ in the cyclic group theorems.